# Error putMondrianSchema MondrianCatalogHelper.ERROR_0004 pentaho error

Tags: java, pentaho

hello I have this error and pentaho crashes. can someone help me?

```
2015-01-21 17:19:51,936 ERROR [org.pentaho.platform.dataaccess.datasource.wizard.service.impl.AnalysisDatasourceService] Error putMondrianSchema MondrianCatalogHelper.ERROR_0004 - already exists status = 8
2015-01-21 17:20:56,187 ERROR [org.pentaho.platform.dataaccess.datasource.wizard.service.impl.AnalysisDatasourceService] Error putMondrianSchema MondrianCatalogHelper.ERROR_0004 - already exists status = 8
```

Comment: I suggest trying the Pentaho forums.

Comment: thank for your replay, but I have already tried in Pentaho forum but nobody answered. thank you

Answer (score 0):

This is because your license for "Pentaho Analysis Enterprise Edition" is either expired or non-existant.  I just hit it :)